# auto increment based on company in laravel migration

Tags: laravel

I need to create a migration with a sequence column basedd on the companyid;

```
companyID sequence
1         1
1         2
2         1
2         2
```

Is there a way i can use migrations to create a auto-increment column(sequence) that increments based on the company id and not just auto-increments the column as a whole?

This is what i have so far.

```
$table->unsignedInteger('companyID');
$table->foreign('companyID')->references('id')->on('company');
$table->increments('sequence');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it with then `increments` field `sequence`. `increments` will increase the value by 1. You have to increase the value of sequence column basedd on the companyid manually.

I guess your model name is `Company`. So while creating a new record, first create the record and then count the occurrences of the company id. After that update the sequence field with the count

```
$company = Company::create(['companyID' => 1, 'sequence'=>0]);
$count = Company::where('companyID', 1)->count();
$company->sequence = $count;
$company->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use MYSQL triggers for this purpose:

```
    public function up()
    {
        DB::unprepared('
            CREATE TRIGGER sequence_trigger
            BEFORE INSERT
               ON companies FOR EACH ROW

            BEGIN
               DECLARE sequence_t int;
               SELECT IFNULL(MAX(sequence), 0) + 1 INTO sequence_t WHERE companyID = NEW.companyID ;
               SET NEW.sequence = sequence_t;
            END;
        ');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        DB::unprepared('DROP TRIGGER `sequence_trigger`');
    }
```

A trigger is an SQL code executed with an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE event.

Comment: This is a better answer and more clean, as I think this more appropriate to be done in DB layer.